# Microsoft Azure chatbot

Tags: c#, angular, .net-6.0, azure-bot-service

I am busy working on a service desk chatbot. I am using .net 6 web api for my backend coding and micrsoft azure bot service and CLU in language studio from Azure.
I have tested my bot locally using the bot framework emulator and it did work.
On azure I created the language studio recource. I also deployed my project as a web app and used the domain as my endpoint url like this: 'https://autodocschatbot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages'.
I also use direct line tokens to authenticate the message. I have tested this and II do get a direct line token.

Now when I try to test my bot on my frontend Angular application I can see that the message is being processed but the bots response is always null and I have no idea why. I have checked everything. For some reason testing it in web chat also does not work.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A couple questions, if you are still having an issue. What is generating the response? Is the response coming directly from the bot or is it a processed response from CLU? The problem may be in how the CLU response is being handled which may explain why it appears the bot is correctly handling the activity.

Comment: Also, if you just run the bot separate from service desk, Angular, and anything else, and send/receive activity via Postman, does the same issue persist? If so, then I would debug the bot using VS and check how each process is handling the to-be-returned activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the webchat channel
[image]
Copy out the URL in the embedded code, fill your webchat secret behind.
[image]
Then just visit this URL directly in browser.
[image]
If this works, you could use the whole embeded code in your html.